# Set 2016 Outlook's Sensitivity using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have developed a tool using C# .net, which sends an email using outlook with help of namespace-

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

The problem I am facing is, recently in my organisation Outlook is enabled with the Sensitivity tag as below image

[image]
Due to this setting, all emails are sent as "Internal and Restricted" by default and receiver will see the unwanted text attached in the mail body as

**Sensitivity: Internal & Restricted**

I tried to set sensitivity in the code using below line. But it didnt helped.

```
newMail.Sensitivity = Outlook.OlSensitivity.olNormal;
```

Please assist me in solving this problem. 
Main intention is to avoid unwanted text to be shown to end users.

Comment: It is very possible that your sensitivity is something else than what Outlook interop considers `Sensitivity` e-mail property. You should check e-mail source codes of specifically tagged e-mails to find out what property it is. You can see the source code by clicking right mouse button in Outlook e-mail body and selecting "View Source".

Comment: <p class=msipfooter45f6f230><span style='font-size:8.0pt;color:black'>Sensitivity:
  Internal &amp; Restricted</span>

Comment: I tried hiding in css:      p.msipfooter45f6f230 {
                                        mso-hide:all;
                                    }    But the class name= msipfooter45f6f230 changes machine to machine.

Comment: Would you be able to determine when is this added to the e-mail body? Whether that happens before or after Outlook client processing?

Comment: It is added after email is sent.